# PowerApps SortBy - against lookup value

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

This works, this is the value of the BrowseGallery1 Items....

```
 SortByColumns(Filter([@'ExternalContacts'],
    StartsWith(Company.Value,SearchInput.Text)||SearchInput.Text in 'Display Name'),**"Title"**,
If(SortDescending1,Ascending,Descending))
```

Instead of title, I want to sort by the value of the Company. Now, company is a **lookup list** and in the filter I have to do a special entry of Company.Value for it to work...

I really want to sortbycolumns "Company.Value" but everytime I do that, there's no data. I tried ...
simply ,Company, and ,"Company", and ,"Company.Value", and ,Company.Value, and every version produces no data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try changing `SortByColumns` with `Sort` and then use `Company.Value`
Let me know if this helps

Comment: Yes, brilliant. It worked. I spent a number of hours researching this last night and I was on the verge of dropping lookup columns from my sharepoint list in favor of using powerapps for customizing the form, but this solved it in a 1 second edit. Thank you...

Odd - why can't I tag your response as "answered"

Comment: Let me add my comment as answer and then you can. It will help others as well

Comment: Added answer. Please mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Your will have to change `SortByColumns` with `Sort` and then use Company.Value

This shall help.